# Can I regain control of a browser that throws an exception in Ruby/Watir

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir

I'm trying to use Watir to automate a process for the museum in which I volunteer, by using it to login to a website and generate a report. I know that Chrome doesn't allow multiple instances to access the same user profile, but I can catch and rescue the exception raised by the Browser.new statement:
browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, options: {args: args}

Chrome, however, recovers and the browser window opens in the existing browser session, thus auto-filling the user name and password fields (which is what I'm after). But the browser variable is not set, such that I have no control and can't even do browser.close.

I could copy the user's profile and use that when starting the browser, but I may then have to solve the problem of the user changing their password. Is there a way that I can regain control of the browser, or am I going to have to address the password change problem?

Comment: what exception are you seeing?

Comment: I get "Unable to move the cache: Access is denied" in trying to copy GPUCache to old_GPUCache_000. From there on, the messages are about being unable to create the cache, Shader Cache Creation failed: -2, and Error reading broker pipe: The pipe has been ended. (0x6D).

Comment: After that there's the traceback which ends with "Backtrace:: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidArgumentError)".

Comment: there's a way to do this actually by starting the browser with a specific debug port. I'll try to put an example together.